# SalesForce, Mule ESB and Heroku and IaaS and PaaS

Tags: heroku, salesforce, mule, esb, paas

Where is Mule ESB intended to be on a cloud

SalesForce appears to be a huge offering.

I assume the Heroku component will always reside on a IaaS (probably AWS)

I am still confused on where the Mule ESB would actually sit.  WOuld that sit inside an IaaS that Heroku might be on

WOuld the Mule ESB sit on a Legacy system to integrate the Heroku requests with the traditional legacy

Would Mule ESB sit on the Iaas to actually simulate a PaaS app server

If it does sit on an IaaS, would you have to installe the Mule ESB manually, or would it come as a cloud option on one of the IaaS, like Azure PaaS on Azure IaaS

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MuleESB is a container (just like tomcat, jboss are). IaaS providers could provide or not integration, to be honest I havent gathered to find out who provides it or not as I usually use Cloudhub.

However, the natural cloud choice for deploying an application to the cloud would be [CloudHub](http://www.cloudhub.io/), an PaaS for Mule Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Mule ESB is intended to sit between apps as an integration bus.  So data in one application can be replicated/transformed/transferred to another application.  Mule ESB itself is an application container, so it will need to be installed on a server somewhere if you don't use Cloudhub.

You would develop an integration application with Anypoint Studio and deploy that app to Mule ESB or Cloudhub.

CloudHub itself is a way of deploying Mule Applications into a cloud computing platform (EC2 on AWS) without worrying at all about the infrastructure behind it.  Most "Cloud" computing just means you don't worry about where it goes because everything can talk to everything anyway.  So Mule can sit in the "Cloud" in a lot of different ways:

1. You can use your own datacenter and install it onto a server that
   you own
2. You can create an Amazon EC2 Instance (or any other cloud
   platform provider) and install Mule into that instance
3. You can use CloudHub to run your app directly and not instantiate your own
   instances, letting CloudHub run that for you.

"Cloud Computing" is a way to abstract away some of the commodity infrastructure of computing.  But you will always need a CPU/Memory/Storage/OS somewhere, what model you choose depends on how much you want to manage personally.